# Al cerrar el primer formulario se cierra la aplicacion C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo 2 formularios porque al cerrar el primer formulario que se abrio se cierra la aplicacion C# (Visual Studio) ?

Primer Formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio recuerda, agregar el código como texto, hay usuarios que no pueden visualizar tu código, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que estas cerrando el form que defines como start up en la aplicacion.

Si revisas `Program.cs` veras una linea

```
Application.Run(new NombreForm());
```

Si cierras el form que alli se define la aplicacion termina